# fast read less structure ascii data file in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, io

I would like to read a data grid (3D array of floats) from .xsf file. (format documentation is here http://www.xcrysden.org/doc/XSF.html the BEGIN_BLOCK_DATAGRID_3D block )

the problem is that data are in 5 columns and if the number of elements Nx*Ny*Nz is not divisible by 5 than **the last line can have any length**.
For this reason I'm not able to use ***numpy.genfromtxt()*** ***of numpy.loadtxt()*** ...

I made a subroutine which does solve the problem, but is terribly slow (  because it use tight loops probably ). The files i want to read are large ( >200 MB  200x200x200 = 8000000 numbers in ASCII  )

Is there any **really fast way how to read such unfriendly formats** in python / numpy into ndarray?

---

xsf datagrids looks like this (example for shape=(3,3,3))

```
BEGIN_BLOCK_DATAGRID_3D
 BEGIN_DATAGRID_3D_this_is_3Dgrid          
 3  3  3         # number of elements Nx Ny Nz                     
 0.0 0.0 0.0     # grid origin in real space                     
 1.0 0.0 0.0     # grid size in real space                    
 0.0 1.0 0.0                               
 0.0 0.0 1.0                          
   0.000  1.000  2.000  5.196  8.000   # data in 5 columns     
   1.000  1.414  2.236  5.292  8.062        
   2.000  2.236  2.828  5.568  8.246        
   3.000  3.162  3.606  6.000  8.544        
   4.000  4.123  4.472  6.557  8.944                   
   1.000  1.414                       # this is the problem
  END_DATAGRID_3D                      
 END_BLOCK_DATAGRID_3D
```

Comment: What is the output of your existing function on this data?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand your question. The resulting 3D array is just: 
[[[0.000, 1.000,  2.000], [5.196, 8.000, 1.000], [ 1.414,  2.236,  5.292]] [[8.062, 2.000,  2.236], [2.828,  5.568,  8.246], [3.000,  3.162,  3.606]], [[6.000,  8.544, 4.000], [4.123, 4.472, 6.557], [8.944, 1.000,  1.414]]]

Answer (score 0):

I got something working with Pandas and Numpy. Pandas will fill in nan values for the missing data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("xyz.data", header=None, delimiter=r'\s+', dtype=np.float, skiprows=7, skipfooter=2)
data = df.values.flatten()
data = data[~np.isnan(data)]
result = data.reshape((data.size/3, 3))
```

Output

```
>>> result
array([[ 0.   ,  1.   ,  2.   ],
       [ 5.196,  8.   ,  1.   ],
       [ 1.414,  2.236,  5.292],
       [ 8.062,  2.   ,  2.236],
       [ 2.828,  5.568,  8.246],
       [ 3.   ,  3.162,  3.606],
       [ 6.   ,  8.544,  4.   ],
       [ 4.123,  4.472,  6.557],
       [ 8.944,  1.   ,  1.414]])
```